# Making a delay between touch events emulated

Tags: android

I am making a piano app in which I need to emulate pressing keys in order to show the user the notes of a song. By using a handler, I am able to make a delay pressing up and down a key.

However, I am not able to make a delay between all the keys which have to be touched. I thought something like this, but I only see the last 2 notes get pressed and sound.

```
    final String[] keys = {"1b","2w","9b","10w","11b","12w"};
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        final int nextKey = i+1;

        //Method in which I used other handler to delay pressing up and down
        pressKey(keys[i]); 

        //Next key i would like to get pressed with a delay
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pressKey(keys[nextKey]);
            }
        },1500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `for`, use a runnable that will keep posting itself with the specified delay:

```
new Runnable()
{
    int nextKey = 0;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        pressKey(keys[nextKey]);

        if (++nextKey < keys.length)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
        // else no more keys
    }
}.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel kinda stupid after all the night trying to figure it out. I just had to make a variable with the delay, and increment it in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a thread if in pressKey method there is no work that needs to be done in the UI thread.

```
new Thread(
new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
         pressKey(keys[i]);
         Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
}
}
).run();
```